# MySQL Stopped unexpecedly on Plesk and cant start

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-server-2012, plesk, windows-server-2012-r2

I've read all the information on internet and tried everything but no solution worked...

Everything was fine and there was no change made on the server or websites, but unexpectedly Mysql stopped working and cant start.

I've looked into service monitor and error says:

> The process terminated unexpectedly. (Error code 1067) at Start
>   service MySQL56 at (service::startStopService line 994) at Error
>   occurred on starting MySQL server. Errors in MySQL error log file:
>
> (LocalServiceHelper::_startMySqlService line 242) at
>   (LocalServiceHelper::_startMySqlService line 245) at Configuration of
>   MySQL Service(LocalServiceHelper::_configureService line 228) at
>   execute console command --repair-local-service(vconsoleapp::start line
>   122) at execute "C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\admin\bin\mysqlmng.###"
>   --repair-local-service(vconsoleapp::run line 139) Execute file name: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\admin\bin\mysqlmng.###